# Flyback transformer driven using a H-bridge damages flyback?

Tags: transformer, high-voltage, high-frequency

I tried driving a flyback transformer salvaged from an old tv, a couple of days ago using a H-bridge driver which I made in past. The pwm signal used to drive is between 62KHz to around 8MHz, this generated by an arduino. At 62Khz (Potentiometer is used to vary the frequency) arcs made from flyback is weaker while I increased the frequency around 600KHz or higher (I wasn't measuring) arcs became very strong and after a while everything stopped then there is some noise coming from the inside of the flyback and no arcs made. Then I got another flyback today, I thought previous one was a faulty one and I did the same mistake as I did back then and guess what the this flyback is also gone.

What could be the reason behind this? I assume there was an insulation breakdown between windings because the stronger arc frequency is it's resonance frequency and energy was high enough? Unluckily I had no 2n3055 transistor to drive this, I used it at my first time of using the flyback transformer.

Also, those fly-backs I got are both rectified ones.

Comment: Excessive voltages can damage flybacks. Colour TVs generated about 25-30kV that way. And I believe they fed the flyback into a diode tripler, suggesting they generated about 8-10kV at the secondary itself. They were also made down to a budget; they wouldn't be designed to withstand any voltage higher than necessary. From information about arcs in air, estimate your arc voltages.

Comment: Driving the transformer at hundreds of kHz or even MHz seems excessive

Comment: Old TV means the flyback is meant to be driven at between 15 and 16 kHz.